# ThreeJS 2D bounding box of 3D object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need figure out the area on screen which my 3D object uses.

I've tried to Google for an answer but with no success.

The function `geometry.computeBoundingBox()` is only returning the 3D bounding box.

How could I convert this to a 2D bounding box?

Comment: This sounds like a good challenge. Will the object or camera be animated? If so, do you need to compute the screen space it occupies once per frame?

Comment: Yes it will, and I am very surprised that it's not implemented yet. Both can be animated, but I have an idea. Brb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply have to convert all vertices to screen space and make a 2D bounding box from them:

```
function computeScreenSpaceBoundingBox(mesh, camera) {
  var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
  var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  var min = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1);
  var max = new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, -1);

  for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    var vertexWorldCoord = vertex.copy(vertices[i]).applyMatrix4(mesh.matrixWorld);
    var vertexScreenSpace = vertexWorldCoord.project(camera);
    min.min(vertexScreenSpace);
    max.max(vertexScreenSpace);
  }

  return new THREE.Box2(min, max);
}
```

The resulting Box2 is in normalized screen coordinates [-1, 1]. You can get the pixels by multiplying with half of the height and width of your renderer:

```
function normalizedToPixels(coord, renderWidthPixels, renderHeightPixels) {
  var halfScreen = new THREE.Vector2(renderWidthPixels/2, renderHeightPixels/2)
  return coord.clone().multiply(halfScreen);
}
```

See a demonstration of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/holgerl/6fy9d54t/

EDIT: Reduced memory usage in inner loop by suggestion from @WestLangley

EDIT2: Fixed a bug discovered by @manthrax

Comment: How many instances are you creating per second? Do not call `new` or `clone()` in tight loops. Refactor your code and fiddle to create a single instance and reuse it using `copy()` or `set()`.

Comment: Good point. I have updated the inner loop now, to reduce the instances created. It obviously could be further optimized by making the bounding box a property on the mesh that is updated wheen needed. Plus some other optimizations. But I want to keep the code easy to read, as my main point was how the original questions can be answered.  @WestLangley

Comment: @HolgerL I moved the camera in your fiddle up and the minimum bounding rectangle of the mesh is not drawn correctly anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/eL3n9y6r/1/ What causes this issue?

Comment: The logic in this solution is wrong. Initializing min and max to 1 and -1 is wrong. They should both be initialized to the value of the first vertex computed.
Inside the loop:

if(i==0){
  min.copy(vertexScreenSpace)
  max.copy(vertexScreenSpace)
}

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. However, there is another bug. The minimum bounding rectangle is still drawn if the object is behind the camera: http://jsfiddle.net/h7rujdkq/1/

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but here is a version that handles groups, children, and buffered geometry:

```js
function computeScreenSpaceBoundingBox(obj, camera) {
    var min;
    var max;

    // Is this an array of objects?
    if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
            let box2 = computeScreenSpaceBoundingBox(obj[i], camera);
            if(min === undefined) {
                min = box2.min.clone();
                max = box2.max.clone();
            } else {
                min.min(box2.min);
                max.max(box2.max);
            }
        }
    }

    // Does this object have geometry?
    if(obj.geometry !== undefined) {
        var vertices = obj.geometry.vertices;
        if(vertices === undefined
            && obj.geometry.attributes !== undefined
            && 'position' in obj.geometry.attributes) {
            // Buffered geometry
            var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();       
            var pos = obj.geometry.attributes.position;
            for(var i = 0; i < pos.count * pos.itemSize; i += pos.itemSize)
            {
                vertex.set(pos.array[i], pos.array[i + 1], pos.array[1 + 2]);
                var vertexWorldCoord = vertex.applyMatrix4(obj.matrixWorld);
                var vertexScreenSpace = vertexWorldCoord.project(camera);
                if(min === undefined) {
                    min = vertexScreenSpace.clone();
                    max = vertexScreenSpace.clone();
                }
                min.min(vertexScreenSpace);
                max.max(vertexScreenSpace);
            }
        } else {
            // Regular geometry
            var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();       
            for(var i = 0; i < vertices.length; ++i) {
                var vertexWorldCoord = vertex.copy(vertices[i]).applyMatrix4(obj.matrixWorld);
                var vertexScreenSpace = vertexWorldCoord.project(camera);
                if(min === undefined) {
                    min = vertexScreenSpace.clone();
                    max = vertexScreenSpace.clone();
                }
                min.min(vertexScreenSpace);
                max.max(vertexScreenSpace);
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Does this object have children?
    if(obj.children !== undefined) {
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; ++i) {
            let box2 = computeScreenSpaceBoundingBox(obj.children[i], camera);
            if(min === undefined) {
                min = box2.min.clone();
                max = box2.max.clone();
            } else {
                min.min(box2.min);
                max.max(box2.max);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return new THREE.Box2(min, max);
}
```

Comment: Your code returns a Box2 with min/max as Vector3, this is wrong and should not happen. Please correct your code.

Comment: @vaid, this is exactly as intended. The original question was to get a 2D bounding box 
 in screen coordinates from a 3D bounding box in world coordinates.

Comment: aah I see. Could you make it so it returns the bounding rect instead? I have kind of managed to get it to work with my own code, but it's still a bit weird. Want to help? I have made a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70863697/2d-bounding-rect-from-a-mesh?noredirect=1#comment125286011_70863697

Comment: @scscsc Hi, you have typping error in your code in vertex set. You have pos.array[1+2] and I think it should be pos.array[i+2].

Answer (score 1):

I am late too. But I rewrite scscsc code to typescript. And I add one more future to it. I computing bbox only from visible objects/meshes.

Coordinates are in [-1, 1], to get sizes just multiply this values by size of canvas.

Edit: I add normalize after projection, because in some cases i get negative or bigger values then [-1, 1].

```
computeScreenSpaceBoundingBox(obj: Object3D, camera: Camera): Box2 {
    let min: Vector2 | undefined = undefined;
    let max: Vector2 | undefined = undefined;

    // Is this an array of objects?
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
        if (obj[i].visible) {
          const box2 = Utils3D.computeScreenSpaceBoundingBox(obj[i], camera);
          if (min === undefined) min = box2.min.clone();
          else min.min(box2.min);

          if (max === undefined) max = box2.max.clone();
          else max.max(box2.max);
        }
      }
    }

    // Does this object have geometry?
    if (obj.visible) {
      if (obj instanceof Mesh && obj.geometry !== undefined) {
        const vertices = obj.geometry.vertices;
        if (vertices === undefined && obj.geometry.attributes !== undefined && "position" in obj.geometry.attributes) {
          // Buffered geometry
          const vertex = new Vector3();
          const pos = obj.geometry.attributes.position;
          for (let i = 0; i < pos.count * pos.itemSize; i += pos.itemSize) {
            vertex.set(pos.array[i], pos.array[i + 1], pos.array[i + 2]);
            const vertexWorldCoord = vertex.applyMatrix4(obj.matrixWorld);
            const vertexScreenSpace = vertexWorldCoord.project(camera).normalize();
            if (min === undefined) {
              min = new Vector2(vertexScreenSpace.x, vertexScreenSpace.y);
            } else {
              Utils3D.min(min, vertexScreenSpace);
            }

            if (max === undefined) max = new Vector2(vertexScreenSpace.x, vertexScreenSpace.y);
            else Utils3D.max(max, vertexScreenSpace);
          }
        } else {
          // Regular geometry
          const vertex = new Vector3();
          for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; ++i) {
            const vertexWorldCoord = vertex.copy(vertices[i]).applyMatrix4(obj.matrixWorld);
            const vertexScreenSpace = vertexWorldCoord.project(camera).normalize();
            if (min === undefined) {
              min = new Vector2(vertexScreenSpace.x, vertexScreenSpace.y);
            } else {
              Utils3D.min(min, vertexScreenSpace);
            }

            if (max === undefined) max = new Vector2(vertexScreenSpace.x, vertexScreenSpace.y);
            else Utils3D.max(max, vertexScreenSpace);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Does this object have children?
    if (obj.children !== undefined) {
      for (let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; ++i) {
        if (obj.children[i].visible) {
          const box2 = Utils3D.computeScreenSpaceBoundingBox(obj.children[i], camera);
          if (min === undefined) min = box2.min.clone();
          else min.min(box2.min);

          if (max === undefined) max = box2.max.clone();
          else max.max(box2.max);
        }
      }
    }

    return new Box2(min, max);
  }
```

Utils3D functions which I use, because there was error in types.

```
 static min(v2: Vector2, v3: Vector3): void {
    if (v2.x > v3.x) v2.x = v3.x;
    if (v2.y > v3.y) v2.y = v3.y;
  }

  static max(v2: Vector2, v3: Vector3): void {
    if (v2.x < v3.x) v2.x = v3.x;
    if (v2.y < v3.y) v2.y = v3.y;
  }
```

Comment: Thx for this; it works for me. Specifically you are successfully taking object rotation into account (for buffered geometry anyways), something that the snippet from @scscsc lacked. For my particular context I had to strip out Typescript, lol. Side note: perhaps `new Vector3()` should be `new THREE.Vector3()` ? I guess it depends on one's init setup.

Comment: Yea new Vector3() is THREE.Vector3(). I using in my project normal imports, I don't like write THREE. againg and again. So I importing Vector3 like import {Vector3} from "three".

Comment: Additional note for others: I had to remove `.normalize()` from the line `vertexWorldCoord.project(camera).normalize()` because I was still not getting 100% precise bounding (pieces of object visually appearing outside of bounds). I believe it's because I'm using non-default camera fov? Needs scrutiny.

Comment: I think FOV is OK. I had some issues with models which have not uniform scale. This help me to minimaze error, but it should work without it's. (My case is little special).