# three.js Orthographic Camera: Zoom All

Tags: javascript, three.js, orthographic

I am a complete newbee to `three.js`, and I cannot find out how to implement a "zoom all" with a `OrthograpicCamera`. I have been searching on the documentation and on the web, and I have only found solutions for `PerspectiveCamera`, that involve altering the field of view.

My goal is to achieve a fitting of all the 3D objects of a scene to the screen, so they are shown as bigger as possible. Any ideas to achieve this will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I do. The `OrthographicCamera` object has the attribute `projectionMatrix`. And I have the bounding box of the object that I want to show (in fact, it is a cube).

Comment: I have posted the code I have developed and the approach that I am using right now here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996637/three-js-orthographic-camera-zoom-all-for-a-cube-with-perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate the 2D screen space bounding box around all the objects, and then use that to set the height and width of the orthographic camera. See how to calculate it here: [ThreeJS 2D bounding box of 3D object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860183/threejs-2d-bounding-box-of-3d-object/45879073#45879073)