# three.js orthographic camera: zoom all for a cube with perspective

Tags: javascript, three.js, orthographic, projection-matrix

I have developed a simple `three.js` application that renders a cube. I have created three files: `index.html`, `viewer_style.css` and `viewer.js`.

The content of `index.html` is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='viewer_style.css'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="viewer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the content of `viewer.js` is the following:

```
// SCENE
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// CAMERA
var frustumHeight;
var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(- frustumHeight * aspect / 2, frustumHeight * aspect / 2, frustumHeight / 2, - frustumHeight / 2, 1, 2000 );
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 100;

// CUBE        
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xbaf5e8, flatShading: true});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(cube);

// BOUNDING BOX
var helper_bbox = new THREE.BoxHelper(cube);
helper_bbox.update();
scene.add(helper_bbox);

// AXES
var helper_axes = new THREE.AxisHelper();
scene.add(helper_axes);

// FIT ALL:
var bbox_radius = helper_bbox.geometry.boundingSphere.radius;
if(aspect < 1){
    frustumHeight = 2 * bbox_radius;
}
else{
    frustumHeight = 2 * bbox_radius / aspect;
}
camera.left = - frustumHeight * aspect / 2;
camera.right = frustumHeight * aspect / 2;
camera.top = frustumHeight / 2;
camera.bottom = - frustumHeight / 2;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

// RENDERER
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

// LIGHTS
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x101010, 1.0); 
scene.add(ambientLight); 
directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0); 
directionalLight.position.set(1.0, 1.0, 1.0).normalize(); 
scene.add(directionalLight); 
directionalLight_2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0); 
directionalLight_2.position.set(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0).normalize(); 
scene.add(directionalLight_2); 

// CONTROLS
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize(){   
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.left   = - frustumHeight * aspect / 2;
    camera.right  =   frustumHeight * aspect / 2;
    camera.top    =   frustumHeight / 2;
    camera.bottom = - frustumHeight / 2;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);  
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

animate();
```

I intend to fit the cube to the scene with a certain margin using the radius of the bounding sphere of the cube. It seems to work correctly, as it can be seen in the following image:

[image]

However, I changed the camera position in `viewer.js` to the following:

```
camera.position.x = 100;
camera.position.y = 100;
camera.position.z = 100;
```

In this situation, I get something like this:

[image]

In this case, the cube is not fitted to the screen. I think this is due to the fact that I am measuring the radius of the bounding sphere in the wrong reference system. However, I have not been able to find a solution to this issue.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Am I using the right approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Change `aspect < 1` to `aspect > 1`. Rename `frustumSize` to `frustumHeight` for clarity.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question, changing `frustumSize` to `frustumHeight`. I have also tried to change `aspect < 1` to `aspect > 1`, but I do not get the desired result either. In fact, the cube is now bigger in the screen. I have not added this last change to the question, as I do not understand well why you suggested this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct if you change `aspect < 1` to `aspect > 1`, as suggested. Here is a jsfiddle with your code that demonstrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/holgerl/kk5h39qa/

Comment: Thank you, now it works perfectly (silly mistake). However, now I have another problem. I have implemented a button with the "zoom all" functionality. Should I change something from the controls apart from the position of the camera and its width and height? It keeps doing strange things when I pan the object and then click the mentioned button.