# Fit OrthographicCamera to Cube

Tags: javascript, three.js, orthographic

I have a three.js scene with a cuboid and an OrthographicCamera:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var aspect = canvas.width/canvas.height;
var size = 1000;

var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(size * aspect / - 2, size * aspect / 2, size / 2, size / - 2, 1, 2000);

camera.position.x = -400;
camera.position.y = 200;
camera.position.z = 400;

camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

var box = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(someWidth, someHeight, someDepth), 
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
);

scene.add(box);
```

The size and proportions of the cuboid vary. How do I derive the camera properties from the cuboid, so that it fits neatly in the center of the camera view (with a small margin on all sides)?

Comment: If you understand what the orthographic camera constructor parameters represent, you can answer this question yourself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558085/three-js-orthographic-camera/17567292#17567292).

Comment: Well, if I understood this stuff I wouldn't have to ask at all - but the answer you linked to is quite helpful. I added some code to the question, hopefully that will make it easier to answer. I guess the main problem I'm having is to calculate the bounding box of the cube when it is at an angle with respect to the camera... the rest I should be able to figure out with a bit of trial and error.

Comment: Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995313/three-js-orthographic-camera-zoom-all. An example of your problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996637/three-js-orthographic-camera-zoom-all-for-a-cube-with-perspective

Comment: @GLR: Looks promising... I will give it a go tonight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [three.js orthographic camera: zoom all for a cube with perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996637/three-js-orthographic-camera-zoom-all-for-a-cube-with-perspective)