# 2D bounding rect from a mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to figure out how to get the rect coords of a mesh for 2D projection.

I need X, Y, Width and Height.

After reading many SO posts and various blogs, it seems like none of them work with latest modern Three.JS and the documentation doesn't have a function for it.

How is this achieved?

Currently, I'm looking at using a Box3 and then project the Box3 to screen.

UPDATE My code looks like this

```
rect(mesh, camera, w, h){
        var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
        bbox.min.setFromMatrixPosition(mesh.matrixWorld);
        bbox.max.setFromMatrixPosition(mesh.matrixWorld);
        bbox = {
            min: bbox.min.project(camera),
            max: bbox.max.project(camera)
        }

        var to2D = which => {
            bbox[which] = {
                x: (bbox[which].x + 1) * w / 2,
                y: -(bbox[which].y - 1) * h / 2
            }
        }
        
        to2D('min')
        to2D('max')


        return {
            x: bbox.min.x,
            y: bbox.min.y,
            w: bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x,
            h: bbox.max.y - bbox.min.y
        }
    }

    return rect
}
```

The output is basically a single point with no rect width/height.

Comment: When you say this if for 2D projection, do you mean to the camera, or to some arbitrary 2D space? If it's to the camera, that's easy. Compute the corners of your `Box3` into `Vector3`s, then use `Vector3.project` to convert them into NDC coordinates of your camera. Look at all 8 values and get the max/min X/Y values. Then multiply them out against your canvas dimensions into pixel lengths.

Comment: Following on from @TheJim01's clarification question; do you want to convert the Three.js coodinate system to pixel (screen) coordinate pixel system, i.e. Three.js coordinates to pixel coodinates?

Comment: @TheJim01 Got it. That was my suspicion as well. Will try it.

Comment: @Enijar Correct. Three.js to pixel coords.